# Capture swipe event with jQuery Touch Events (Ben Major)

Tags: jquery, events, swipe

I'm really happy with this little plugin: https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events. But there isn't much documentation. I want to throttle user swipes, and figured it should be easy using the returned 'swipeend' time value. I can't work out how to get the value!

The author's example code works great (below) but I must have tried 100 different permutations & still can't get a timestamp for swipes only. I need this as there is no point throttling normal clicks & scrolls.

```
// works
$('element').on('tapend', function (e, touch) { console.log( 'tapend', touch.time ); })

// doesn't work
$('element').on('swipeend', function (e, touch) { console.log( 'swipeend', touch.time ); }) // undefined
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be easy (after I'd broken my brain reading documentation.)

```js
$( '#one' )
    .on( 'swiperight', function(){
        $( this ).addClass( 'moveright' );
    })
    .on( 'swipeleft', function(){
        $( this ).addClass( 'moveleft' );
    })
    .on( 'swipeup', function( ev, touch ){
        $( this ).removeClass( 'moveleft moveright' );
    })
    .swipeend(function( ev, touch ){  // <=== returns touch event data
        console.log( ev, ev.timeStamp ); 
    });
```

```css
#one {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 #one.moveright {
   transform: translateX( 150% );
   background: red;
 }
 #one.moveleft {
   transform: translate( 50%, 50% );
   background: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-touch-events/1.0.5/jquery.mobile-events.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<p>Swipe right, left and up</p>
```

If you're looking to construct complex events, the amount of [potential data](https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events#5-callback-data) that's returned is incredible. For an adequate time comparison, I subtracted the returned number from `Date.now()`. Apparently this doesn't work correctly in Firefox or IE8, but I don't care enough to discover workarounds.

There are other ways to achieve a simple event throttle, of course. In most cases one could remove the handlers with [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [set a timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Example) before adding them back.